# change marginLeft on every swipe event

Tags: javascript

Im trying to decrese the marginLeft on each swipe, but it only works the first time then the `marginLeft` is `-200px` and it doesn't change. How can i make it decrease `200px` every time, so first `marginLeft` is `0`, second swipe `-200px` tired `-400px` and so on?

```
var visits = document.getElementById('visits');

// create a simple instance
// by default, it only adds horizontal recognizers
var visits = new Hammer(visits);

// listen to events...
visits.on("panleft", function(ev) {
    document.getElementById('visits').style.marginLeft = '-200px' 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
visits.on("panleft", function(ev) {
    var curr = parseInt(document.getElementById('visits').style.marginLeft, 10) || 0;
    document.getElementById('visits').style.marginLeft = (curr - 200) + 'px'; 
});
```

Currently you are setting margin-left to 200px every pan left (So it gets set to -200 the 1st time, -200 the 2nd, -200 on the 3rd and so on)